# Is there a way to duplicate data from one google sheet doc to another google sheet doc, when data is added

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a jot form that submits data to one dedicated google sheet (DGS). I work primarily with one google sheet doc that copies cell data from the DGS. I'm trying to implement a code that when new data is entered to duplicate data and send to the google sheet doc I use regularly.

*Note. If I try to alter the DGS, it throws an error and distorts the data sent.

```
function copydata()
 {
 var sourceSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Google Sheet ID").getSheetByName("Tab Sheet Name");

 var targetSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("Google Sheet ID").getSheetByName("Tab Sheet Name");

 var rangeToCopyFrom = sourceSheet.getRange(sourceSheet.getLastRow(), 2, 1, 15);
 var rangeToPasteTo =  targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow(),1,1,15);

 var rangeToCopyFrom = sourceSheet.getRange("A50:N50");
 var rangeToPasteTo =  targetSheet.getRange("A4:N4");

 rangeToCopyFrom.copyTo(rangeToPasteTo, {contentsOnly:true});
 }
```

Comment: You are declaring `rangeToCopyFrom` twice and the second is a different range than the first.  Same with `rangeToPasteTo` N is column 14

Comment: He you looked at using onFormSubmit Trigger from the DGS

Answer (score 0):

This could be us to append data to another spreadsheet:

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  const sh = dss.getSheetByName("Destination Sheet Name");
  sh.appendRow(e.values);
}
```

It needs to go into DGS.  I'd need to know more about the date to determine if it's not duplicate data